# How to use MATLAB to observe the effect of multiple damping factors?

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

I want to use MATLAB to observe the effect of changing zeta (damping factor) on system response?

Here is a m-file code that plots three responses: underdamped, overdamped and critically damped.

```
clc
clear all
close all
num1=[16]
den1=[1 4 16]
num2=[16]
den2=[1 8 16]
num3=[16]
den3=[1 10 16]
sys1=tf(num1,den1)
```

I have also attached a snapshot of the response:

[image]

I want to do something that allows me to change the value of zeta directly and according to that zeta value the response changes, instead of writing a new transfer function or changing original transfer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm interpreting what you're asking correctly. My understanding is that you just want to simulate the transfer function, for various zeta values, without having to re-define the transfer function?

You can express the zeta variable directly in your denominator array. Consider that the basic second-order transfer function is as follows:

$$ G(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_ns + \omega_n^2}$$

Currently, you're hard-coding the values of each term. You can also define them as variables:

```
omega = 4;

hold on
for zeta = 0.25:0.25:1.5
  num = [omega^2];
  den = [1, omega*zeta*2, omega^2];
  sys = step(tf(num, den));
  plot(sys, 'DisplayName', ["z = ", num2str(zeta)]);
end
hold off

title("Step Response with varied Zeta");
legend show
```

[image: Step Response]

Code run in Octave 5.1 which doesn't support `stepplot` so I substituted `step`. If there are specific and random values for \$\zeta\$ that you want to test, you could also run this over an array.

Answer (score 1):

It's called system identification. This is a good starting point:
http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ECE5560/ECE5560-Notes04.pdf

[image]

You could then relate the estimated transfer function back and find zeta.
(if you just want to find zeta now, you can already do that with the numbers you have, and you don't need system identification).

To find an estimated transfer function, you need to know the input and outputs of a system, you can then find the relationship between the inputs and outputs which is the transfer function.

I am fairly sure that this can't be done accurately real-time. To know the frequency response of a system, you need to have enough of the frequency space sampled. But you can do this a short time after the system is settled. (or you could calculate zeta in real time, it might not make sense until the system is settled).

There are other tools and code already written to estimate transfer functions, I hope this gives you a good starting point.